# Assert omission with empty assert body

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make an assertion function that omit's a key from an object. Here is my code:

```
function doit() {
    const test: { foo: true, bar: true } = { foo: true, bar: true }

    assertTestDoesntHaveBar(test);

    const bar = test.bar
}

function assertTestDoesntHaveBar<T extends { bar: boolean }> (obj: T): asserts obj is Omit<typeof obj, 'bar'> {
    // empty body
}
```

And playground - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzjKAKAlIg3gKESMQgQGcpEoBTCgLj0WDjgagCcRqAaRAIwCG7Np2qIAvogC8jZqyqjeg4Qq4T8hYgLJlq7KABVaUACJxaYKAAkBAN2oAhIRhoUsAbg3ES5SsulUxgB0yvjiGqCQsAiI2rr6RhRmFtZ2jkIAPAaI1AAeNGDIZIzKDHwsADbUAkjiAHyIGHB8AFYMBlgMcXpQxc0tiDDFAPIAtugZUACeAA7UcMCI-bwA5MorDQTeAPTbOaMz0-xwyFNhQA

I am intentionally leaving an empty body there. However `bar` still exists. Anyway to make it assert bar is no longer in there?

Comment: Did you notice that you have a compiler error? `Omit<obj, 'bar'>` is not valid as `obj` is not a type.

Comment: Also, if your object needs to extend `{ bar: boolean }`, then why would it not have `bar`?

Comment: @crashmstr thanks for that error I fixed it. the issue remains. This is a simplified case, there are cases that need this, describe one of those cases would make this an XY question and I'll get closed.

Comment: @Noitidart No, the opposite is the case. **This is a XY question** since you are not describing your original problem, but a failed attempt to solve it. You should post your original problem instead.

Comment: The reason this is not working is that type predicates always need to be a sub-type of the parameter. In this case you are doing the opposite since `Omit<T, ...>` will be a super-type of `T`. So it seems to be the design of type predicates that narrowing is supported but widening is not.

Comment: @TobiasS. Ah, so its straight up not possible with assertion to do this.

Comment: @Noitidart yes. But I'm still wondering why you need that. You probably got your typing in a different place wrong.

Comment: If you want to *remove* `bar` from the object that has it, you would not use an assertion or type narrowing, but the `delete` operation in the function body and your return type *could be* `Omit<T, 'bar'>` if subsequent code was typed for that.

Comment: Ah interesting @crashmstr I tested that here, however `bar` is still accesible. This is my exact situation, a library is deleting a property via mutation in my object, so I want to tell my code it no longer exists.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzjKAKAlIg3gKESMQgQGcpEoBTCgLj0WDjgagCcRqAaRAIwCG7Np2qIAvogC8jZqyqjeg4Qq4T8hYgLJlq7KABVaUACJxaYKAAkBAN2oAhIRhoUsAbg3ES5SsulUxgB0yvjiGqCQsAiI2rr6RhRmFtZ2jkIAPAaI1AAeNGDIZIzKAPwMfCwANtQCSOIAfIgYcHwAVgwGOATeyNQ1NIitbSFCnuJAA

Comment: @TobiasS. thanks my problem is a lib is deleting via mutation a key in my object. So I want to tell my code its gone.

Comment: @Noitidart If the type is still `T` and `T` includes `bar`, then yes, it is still a property and there will be no errors trying to use or access it. You would need to assign the object to a `Omit<T, 'bar'>` for the remainder of the code to "know" that `bar` is not a valid property.